# Can you check the stats/gender of starter pokémon in X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is there any way to preview the statistics of the starter pokémon before you choose one?

Comment: Nope. No way at all.

Comment: Thanks. I know there are some button combinations but the user guide information leaflet dose not tell me them :(

Comment: No, and I don't think there are any button combinations that do that. Things like this would have been popular quickly, especially since a lot of people softreset to get shiny starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple, no. After you choose it though, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your starter's stats and gender after you pick it, but there is not a way to check a starter's stats and gender before you pick it.